# Event.target.className — как правильно настроить?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Изучаю делегирование событий

https://jsfiddle.net/nytw2efk/4/

```
  document.querySelector('.income').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.className = "fick") {
        e.target.classList.toggle('redtext');
         alert(e.target.className);     
        }


    })
```

по идее должен при клике меняться цвет, но только у элемента с классом fick
В итоге:
1. при клике меняется цвет у элементов и без класса fick и вообще alert показывает что будто класс fick у каждого элемента
2. при повторном клике toggle не срабатывает

Что не так?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не

```
if (e.target.className = "fick") {
```

а

```
if (e.target.className == "fick") {
```

а еще лучше

```
if (e.target.classList.contains("fick")) {
```

*Что было у Вас:*

оператор присваивания в условии `if` назначал кликнутому элементу (*любому*) атрибут `class="fick"` и возвращал это значение, что в булевском смысле трансформировалось в `true`. То есть код внутри блока `if` всегда выполнялся.

На первый клик по какому-либо элементу его класс сначала становился `"fick"` - внутри условия `if`, а потом `"fick redtext"` - при выполнении `toggle`, и элемент становился красным. При втором клике (и всех последующих кликах) происходило то же самое, и элемент оставался красным.

*Почему не работает с `==`:*

Точное равенство `"icome__title fick"` и `"fick"`, конечно, дает `false`, и код в блоке `if` не выполняется.

Comment: двойное равно вообще остановило работу. А if (e.target.classList.contains("fuck")) {
сработало. Спасибо. Не понимаю почему через className не получалось

Comment: @TheOs Сейчас напишу.

Comment: ok) будет интересно узнать

Comment: Теперь ясно думаю. оператор присваивания в условии if назначал кликнутому элементу (любому) атрибут  class="fick" и возвращал это значение - спасибо ) я не думал что присваивание будет, думал что как проверка что цель имеет этот класс будет, надо мне осторожнее с равно быть ) Получается из-за того что один знак равно был только присвоилось

Comment: Точное равенство "icome__title fick" и "fick" - даже не подумал что он строки сравнивает, а не наличие класса, thanks большое

Comment: Не `e.target.className == "fick"`, а `e.target.className === "fick"` =) Так лучше.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nytw2efk/42/ - все равно повторно toggle не срабатывает . И с тройным равно.

Comment: @TheOs Там все еще одно `=` - присваивание. Но предположим, что их там два (или три) - сравнение. После вызова `toggle` `className` станет тем, что Вы видите в `alert` - `fick redtext`, и проверка на точное равенство опять не подходит. Короче говоря, надо использовать `classList.contains`.

Comment: точно, новый класс же добавился, понял )